# Задать .attr для всех вложенных элементов кроме одного

Tags: jquery

Допустим есть код:

```
<div class="leftb" style=" position: fixed; text-align:center;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 5%; padding-top:15%;
height: 100%; background: black;"><a href="#files"><img src="images/files.png" id="files1"></a><br>
                                <a href="#note"><img src="images/note.png" style="margin-top:10px" id="note1"></a><br>
                                <a href="#settings"><img src="images/settings.png" style="margin-top:10px" id="settings1"></a><br>                          
                                <a href="#pass"><img src="images/pass.png" style="margin-top:10px" id="pass1"></a><br>
                                <a href="#blog"><img src="images/blog.png" style="margin-top:10px" id="blog1"></a><br>  
                                <a href="#info"><img src="images/info.png" style="margin-top:10px" id="info1"></a>
                                </div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при `$("#"+id+"1").attr('src','mm.jpg');` остальным картинкам, чей id не равен #[id]1 установить `src`

Comment: Может быть так: `$('img:not(#'+id+'1)').attr('src', 'images/' + id + '.png')`?

Comment: Так же можно воспользоваться методом `filter` http://api.jquery.com/filter/